# Issue Removing Sitemap Footer Link

Tags: magento-1.7

I spent the morning following instructions to remove the Footer Links, Contact Us, Search Terms, Advanced Search and Sitemap. I was able to remove all the links except Sitemap. I tried a variety of locations for the catalog.xml file but every time I commented out the section that was in the directions my product block disappeared for every product. As soon as I removed the comment it came back. I am flummoxed! Anyone have an experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System-->Configuration-->Catalog-->Search Engine Optimization and then disable Autogenerated Site map.